# Installing Ruby On Rails 3.0 on Mac OS X 10.5.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to install Ruby On Rails 3.0 on my iMac OS X 10.5.8, but everytime i try, i get errors.

On my Macbook Pro, the installation was not a problem.

Anyone know why i can't install this on my iMac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to install it via [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).
de default ruby interpreter of macosx is quite outdated.

once rvm is installed, just perform:

```
rvm install rails
```

Comment: I get this error, when i have installed RVM. 

-bash: rvm: command not found

Comment: have you followed all the instruction and modified your bash profile? after modification you should close the terminal and open an new one.

Comment: can you paste the output of `echo $PATH`?  you should see something like: 
/Users/alor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/alor/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/Users/alor/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/alor/.rvm/bin: and so on....

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/simonthomsen/.rvm/bin:/Users/simonthomsen/.rvm/bin

I get that

Comment: I found this fantastic guide: http://neptunephoenix.blogspot.com/2010/07/error-while-running-make-installing.html - Now is ruby 1.8.6 installed, so i think it works soon! :-)

Comment: But when i try to update my rails, i get this error
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteSourceException)
    HTTP Response 302
Anyone know why?